# Enforcing JWT authentication on GKE using Istio

Tags: kubernetes, istio

We are developing web-app which is backed by a bunch of BFF services deployed on GKE with Istio configured to be injected as a sidecar on every pod in the BFF services.

The requirement here is to

- Enforce a JWT based authentication for all workloads except for the spring actuator endpoints.
- Extract the member_id from the JWT claim and pass it as a header to the service.
- I want to bypass this for "internal" endpoints (from within the network) and when the BFF's are talking internally **(This is where I am stuck)**

Here's what I have working so far.

- Setup a RequestAuthentication as below

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: RequestAuthentication
metadata:
  name: req-auth-jwt-required
  namespace: istio-testing-ns
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: istio-testing-service
  jwtRules:
    - issuer: "https://abc.us.com/"
      jwksUri: https://abc.us.com/.well-known/jwks.json
      outputClaimToHeaders:
        - header: X-MemberId
          claim: x-member-id
---
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: req-auth-policy-authenticated-only
  namespace: istio-testing-ns
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: istio-testing-service
  action: DENY
  rules:
    - from:
        - source:
            notRequestPrincipals: ["*"]
      to:
        - operation:
            notPaths: ["/istio-test/service/v1/actuator*"]
            notHosts: ["internal-*"]
            methods:
              - "GET"
    - to:
        - operation:
            paths:
              - "/istio-test/service/v1/categories*"
            notHosts: ["internal-*"]
            methods:
              - "GET"
              - "POST"
      when:
        - key: request.auth.claims[x-permissions]
          notValues:
            - "categories-lookup"
```

So, Using these two manifests I am trying to meet the above requirement, it is, by and far working, however, the problem, I am running into is below

- When calling the service using the "internal" host, with no JWT and header X-MemberId, the `outputClaimToHeaders`  seems to be over-writing the header because of which the service fails.

Any recommendations on how should I go about meeting this or any other general suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am led to believe this could be a probable bug where the headers are wiped out in case if the JWT is not passed.

Hence, I used the following approach to get around my problem.

In Istio, I used the `outputPayloadToHeader` to pass the verified JWT's payload as a header to the service.

```yaml
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: RequestAuthentication
metadata:
  name: req-auth-jwt-required
  namespace: istio-testing-ns
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: istio-testing-service
  jwtRules:
    - issuer: "https://abc.us.com/"
      jwksUri: https://abc.us.com/.well-known/jwks.json
      outputPayloadToHeader: "X-JWT-Payload"
```

Once the above was done, I wrote a filter in `ClaimExtractingFilter` that basically, extracts the passed in header (X-JWT-Payload) and extract the claims and pass them as headers to the actual service.

Let me know if anyone needs more details about the filter and I'll be happy to provide.